# How long should I charge my headlamp to max. capacity without damaging it?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lamp

I have a headlamp that uses two 6800 mAh batteries connected in parallel. The charger that came with it operates on 4.2V / 500mA.

A forum on the internet said that the time taken to charge = (battery current)/(power supply current)
hence
13600 / 500  = 27 hrs.
Is this correct?

Comment: If you're using a properly designed product it will stop charging automatically when it's complete. It's likely the 500mA is the maximum safe load the supply can deliver, what is actually used may be lower.

Comment: If it is a proper charger for the type of batteries you have, it will stop charging when the batteries are full; no need to worry about the maximum charging time. If it isn't a proper charger but just a power supply, don't use it and get a battery charger instead.

Comment: As  they say - MUST be a proper charger for  cells used AND it will stop when charged if real. || Charge time is longer than 13600/500 in most cases. Most chargers charge at constant current to 4.2V then hold voltage at 4.2V and current tapers off to some predecided lower level. They will charge to about 80-90% in 80 to 90% of 27 hours and then usually slowly taper off for several times longer. Stopping when voltage reaches 4.2V somewhat redcues capacity BUT greatly extends cycle life.\

Answer (score 1):

Short: If you use a proper charger it will stop at the right time. So you won't have to care. In every other case, dispose of it as quickly as possible because it's a fire hazard!

Longer answer:

- Battery capacities are estimates at best, they are never precise
- You only have 80-90% of efficiency in batteries, so when charging with constant current, you have to multiply the time with a factor of 1.1 or 1.2
- This kind of charging can be done on NiCad and Lead Acid batteries when you charge with less than 0.1C (Resulting in Charging times from empty of >10hrs). Don't ever think about doing a dumb constant current charging with Lithium based chemistries. In the best case you'll destroy the battery, in the worst case you burn your house down (your charger being 4.2V points to LiIon or LiPo batteries btw.)
- Batteries are not "empty". You never know how much charge they still hold, so trying to estimate the time until they are fully charged without really smart electronics is futile.

Comment: The product I bought from amazon is most likely a Chinese product and the charger came along with it. There is no indication in the charger or the headlamp that states that the battery has been charged, which is why I was trying to estimate the amount of time it would take me it charge the cells. So I don't have any idea about the right time, do you think i should go with charging it for maybe 20-22 if not 27 in intervals?

Comment: You're probably in luck. Because the power supply can't supply more than 4.2V it can't overcharge the Batteries (they have 4.2V when full). So the charging will go slower and slower towards the end. I'd still recommend to not let them connected longer than 24hrs. You're almost never starting at 0% with a battery (you shouldn't ever fully discharge a Li-Ion battery because they loose capacity pretty quickly than). Are the batteries a standard size? Can they be removed from the lamp?

Comment: Thanks for the help. To answer your question, these aren't standard batteries as far as I know but can be removed from the lamp.
Here is the link to a similar product if u wanna have a look: https://amzn.eu/d/1CkH8wz